# How to dispose existing services instances and inject new service instances in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm working on an AngularJS 1.6 web application.

There are a number of AngularJS services in the web application.  I'm beginning to implement features that use the services to persist state between views.

However, this is becoming problematic when the user logs off and another user logs on.  When the new user logs on, the services persist state from the previously user.  I know that I can theoretically write code to put the application in a specific state when a user logs in, but it seems to me like it would be easier to simply dispose the stateful services and instantiate new ones when a new user logs on.

Is there an expedient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **expedient** way to do this would be when a user logs out, do a hard refresh and send them to the login page.   This should wipe data that is stored in memory across the whole application.

If you dont want to perform a hard refresh, you're just going to have to clear out the data manually for each service, which depending on the amount, could be a fair bit of work and most definitely not expedient.